# unable to get difference of days between two dates in java

Tags: java, date, calendar, days

I want to calculate the difference of days between two dates. My code works fine when the year of the date does not change, but when I calculate the difference between two dates like so: (13/01/2012 to 13/12/2011), it gives a negative value. It also gives wrong values of difference when I calculate the difference between today's date and a future date. Please help me. Thank you in advance. Here is my code:

```
//getting values from text box
String fromtext = from.getText().toString();
String totext = to.getText().toString();
//sdf if a simple date formatter
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date fromdate = (Date) sdf.parse(fromtext);
Date todate = (Date) sdf.parse(totext);

Calendar fromcal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar tocal = Calendar.getInstance();


    fromcal.setTime(fromdate);
    tocal.setTime(todate);// setting to date


    int reportDays=(int)(todate.getTime()-fromdate.getTime())/(3600*24*1000);
```

please tell me what is the best way to calculate the difference in days.

Comment: take a look at [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/DateDifferent.shtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the format issue already mentionned, you are likely to have an overflow.
Try this:

```
int reportDays=(int)((todate.getTime()-fromdate.getTime())/(3600*24*1000));
```

Comment: exactly this is what i was doing wrong.It is working fine now.Thank you so much......:)

Answer (score 6):

Dates input : `13/01/2012`, `13/12/2011`

format seems `dd/MM/yyyy` and you are using wrong one (i.e. `MM/dd/yyyy`)

Comment: sorry it was typing mistake.but whenever i give correct format it returns negative values.......

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    LocalDate.parse( "13/01/2012" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ) ,
    LocalDate.parse( "13/12/2011" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) )
)
```

## Using java.time

Much easier with the modern java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

```
(13/01/2012 to 13/12/2011),
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "13/01/2012" , f );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( "13/12/2011" , f );
```

Use `ChronoUnit` to calculate elapsed days.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop );
```

Of course the number of days is negative when going back in time. Notice how your stop date is earlier than your start date.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

You can use `ChronoUnit` again to count days into the future.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( today , today.plusMonths( 7 ) );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try better googling....

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/DateDiffcomputethedifferencebetweentwodates.htm

Answer (score 0):

Using joda time would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateDifferent{  
  public static void main(String[] args){
  Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
  Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar1.set(2007, 01, 10);
  calendar2.set(2007, 07, 01);
  long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
  long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
  long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
  long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
  long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
  long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
  long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  System.out.println("\nThe Date Different Example");
  System.out.println("Time in milliseconds: " + diff + " milliseconds.");
  System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");
  System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
  System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
  System.out.println("Time in days: " + diffDays + " days.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple little class I wrote for this purpose:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DifferenceInDays
{
    public int dateOffset(String incomingDate) throws ParseException
    {
        // parse dates
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = (Date) formatter.parse(incomingDate);

        // convert to milliseconds
        long millisecs = date.getTime();

        // convert to days
        int offsetInDays = (int) Math.abs(millisecs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        return offsetInDays;
    }
}
```

It takes care of negative offsets using the absolute value method.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this with a locale that has daylight saving, and the from and to dates are before and after a daylight saving change the result may be different by 1 day. This is because `Date` and `Calendar` use timezones.

If you are only going to be dealing with dates between the years 1900 and 2100, there is a simple calculation which will give you the number of days since 1900:

```
public static int daysSince1900(Date date) {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(date);

    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (year < 1900 || year > 2099) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("daysSince1900 - Date must be between 1900 and 2099");
    }
    year -= 1900;
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int days = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    if (month < 3) {
        month += 12;
        year--;
    }
    int yearDays = (int) (year * 365.25);
    int monthDays = (int) ((month + 1) * 30.61);

    return (yearDays + monthDays + days - 63);
}
```

Thus, to get the difference in days between two dates, you calculate their days since 1900 and calc the difference. Our daysBetween method looks like this:

```
public static Integer getDaysBetween(Date date1, Date date2) {
    if (date1 == null || date2 == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int days1 = daysSince1900(date1);
    int days2 = daysSince1900(date2);

    if (days1 < days2) {
        return days2 - days1;
    } else {
        return days1 - days2;
    }
}
```

And don't ask me where this calculation came from because we've used it since the early '90s.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this!

```
package javaapplication2;
//@author Ibrahim Yesilay
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication2 {  


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {



    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);        
        System.out.println("First dates Day :");
        int d = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("First dates Mounth :");
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("First dates Year :");
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        String date;
        date = Integer.toString(d) + "/" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);  
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date firstdate = null;
        firstdate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(firstdate)); 

        System.out.println("Second dates Day :");
        d = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Second dates Month :");
        m = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Second dates Year :");
        y = scan.nextInt();
        date = Integer.toString(d) + "/" + Integer.toString(m) + "/" + Integer.toString(y);  
        Date seconddate = null;
        seconddate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(seconddate)); 

        if (seconddate.getTime() > firstdate.getTime()) {
            long sonuc = (long)(seconddate.getTime()- firstdate.getTime())/(3600*24*1000);
            System.out.println("" + sonuc);
        } else if (firstdate.getTime() > seconddate.getTime()) {
            long sonuc = (long)(firstdate.getTime()- seconddate.getTime())/(3600*24*1000);
            System.out.println("" + sonuc);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The dates are equal!");
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.

Comment: Never do date and time math by hand like this. It’s too complicated and will not always give the correct result. Leave to proven library classes instead. Also don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).